# How can I know whether a java Thread is completed when I use Thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using a Multiple Thread object and Running `run()` of `Runnable` class for downloading images from `URL`. But How can I know that `t.start()` have finished it's work.

My code given below:

Class:    ImageDownLoadThread.java

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;


public class ImageDownLoadThread implements Runnable{
    private String imgURL;
    private String destFile;
    public ImageDownLoadThread(String imgURL, String destFile){
        this.imgURL = imgURL;
        this.destFile = destFile;
    }

    public void run(){

        try{
            URL url = new URL(imgURL);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;
            while( (length = is.read(b)) != -1 ){
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }
            os.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }

}
```

Class: `Main.java`

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Images images = new Images();

        int i = 0;

        for (String imString : images.imageUrls) {
            ImageDownLoadThread imageDownLoadThread = new ImageDownLoadThread(imString, Integer.toString(i) + ".jpg");
            Thread t = new Thread(imageDownLoadThread);
            t.start();
            i++;
        }        

    }

}
```

Class: `Images.java`

```
public class Images {

    public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s1024/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s1024/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--L0Km39l5J8/URquXHGcdNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3ZrSJNrSomQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Butte.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s1024/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WIuWgVcU3Qw/URqubRVcj4I/AAAAAAAAAbs/YvbwgGjwdIQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Walls.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UBmLbPELvoQ/URqucCdv0kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IdNhr2VQoQs/s1024/Apre%2525CC%252580s%252520la%252520Pluie.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-s-AFpvgSeew/URquc6dF-JI/AAAAAAAAAbs/Mt3xNGRUd68/s1024/Backlit%252520Cloud.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bvmif9a9YOQ/URquea3heHI/AAAAAAAAAbs/rcr6wyeQtAo/s1024/Bee%252520and%252520Flower.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-n7mdm7I7FGs/URqueT_BT-I/AAAAAAAAAbs/9MYmXlmpSAo/s1024/Bonzai%252520Rock%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4CN4X4t0M1k/URqufPozWzI/AAAAAAAAAbs/8wK41lg1KPs/s1024/Caterpillar.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-rrFnVC8xQEg/URqufdrLBaI/AAAAAAAAAbs/s69WYy_fl1E/s1024/Chess.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WVpRptWH8Yw/URqugh-QmDI/AAAAAAAAAbs/E-MgBgtlUWU/s1024/Chihuly.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-0BDXkYmckbo/URquhKFW84I/AAAAAAAAAbs/ogQtHCTk2JQ/s1024/Closed%252520Door.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PyggXXZRykM/URquh-kVvoI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hFtDwhtrHHQ/s1024/Colorado%252520River%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZAs4dNZtALc/URquikvOCWI/AAAAAAAAAbs/DXz4h3dll1Y/s1024/Colors%252520of%252520Autumn.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-GztnWEIiMz8/URqukVCU7bI/AAAAAAAAAbs/jo2Hjv6MZ6M/s1024/Countryside.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bEg9EZ9QoiM/URquklz3FGI/AAAAAAAAAbs/UUuv8Ac2BaE/s1024/Death%252520Valley%252520-%252520Dunes.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ijQJ8W68tEE/URqulGkvFEI/AAAAAAAAAbs/zPXvIwi_rFw/s1024/Delicate%252520Arch.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Oh8mMy2ieng/URqullDwehI/AAAAAAAAAbs/TbdeEfsaIZY/s1024/Despair.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-gl0y4UiAOlk/URqumC_KjBI/AAAAAAAAAbs/PM1eT7dn4oo/s1024/Eagle%252520Fall%252520Sunrise.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hYYHd2_vXPQ/URqumtJa9eI/AAAAAAAAAbs/wAalXVkbSh0/s1024/Electric%252520Storm.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-PyY_yiyjPTo/URqunUOhHFI/AAAAAAAAAbs/azZoULNuJXc/s1024/False%252520Kiva.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-PYvLVdvXywk/URqunwd8hfI/AAAAAAAAAbs/qiMwgkFvf6I/s1024/Fitzgerald%252520Streaks.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KIR_UobIIqY/URquoCZ9SlI/AAAAAAAAAbs/Y4d4q8sXu4c/s1024/Foggy%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-9lzOk_OWZH0/URquoo4xYoI/AAAAAAAAAbs/AwgzHtNVCwU/s1024/Frantic.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-0X3JNaKaz48/URqupH78wpI/AAAAAAAAAbs/lHXxu_zbH8s/s1024/Golden%252520Gate%252520Afternoon.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-95sb5ag7ABc/URqupl95RDI/AAAAAAAAAbs/g73R20iVTRA/s1024/Golden%252520Gate%252520Fog.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JB9v6rtgHhk/URqup21F-zI/AAAAAAAAAbs/64Fb8qMZWXk/s1024/Golden%252520Grass.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-EIBGfnuLtII/URquqVHwaRI/AAAAAAAAAbs/FA4McV2u8VE/s1024/Grand%252520Teton.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WoMxZvmN9nY/URquq1v2AoI/AAAAAAAAAbs/grj5uMhL6NA/s1024/Grass%252520Closeup.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6hZiEHXx64Q/URqurxvNdqI/AAAAAAAAAbs/kWMXM3o5OVI/s1024/Green%252520Grass.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-6LVb9OXtQ60/URquteBFuKI/AAAAAAAAAbs/4F4kRgecwFs/s1024/Hanging%252520Leaf.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-zAvf__52ONk/URqutT_IuxI/AAAAAAAAAbs/D_bcuc0thoU/s1024/Highway%2525201.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-H4SrUg615rA/URquuL27fXI/AAAAAAAAAbs/4aEqJfiMsOU/s1024/Horseshoe%252520Bend%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JhFi4fb_Pqw/URquuX-QXbI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IXpYUxuweYM/s1024/Horseshoe%252520Bend.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-UGgssvFRJ7g/URquueyJzGI/AAAAAAAAAbs/yYIBlLT0toM/s1024/Into%252520the%252520Blue.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-CH7KoupI7uI/URquu0FF__I/AAAAAAAAAbs/R7GDmI7v_G0/s1024/Jelly%252520Fish%2525202.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-pwuuw6yhg8U/URquvPxR3FI/AAAAAAAAAbs/VNGk6f-tsGE/s1024/Jelly%252520Fish%2525203.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-GoUQVw1fnFw/URquv6xbC0I/AAAAAAAAAbs/zEUVTQQ43Zc/s1024/Kauai.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8QdYYQEpYjw/URquwvdh88I/AAAAAAAAAbs/cktDy-ysfHo/s1024/Kyoto%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vPeekyDjOE0/URquwzJ28qI/AAAAAAAAAbs/qxcyXULsZrg/s1024/Lake%252520Tahoe%252520Colors.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-xBPxWpD4yxU/URquxWHk8AI/AAAAAAAAAbs/ARDPeDYPiMY/s1024/Lava%252520from%252520the%252520Sky.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-897VXrJB6RE/URquxxxd-5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/j-Cz4T4YvIw/s1024/Leica%25252050mm%252520Summilux.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-qSJ4D4iXzGo/URquyDWiJ1I/AAAAAAAAAbs/k2pBXeWehOA/s1024/Leica%25252050mm%252520Summilux.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-dwlPg83vzLg/URquylTVuFI/AAAAAAAAAbs/G6SyQ8b4YsI/s1024/Leica%252520M8%252520%252528Front%252529.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-R3_EYAyJvfk/URquzQBv8eI/AAAAAAAAAbs/b9xhpUM3pEI/s1024/Light%252520to%252520Sand.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fHY5h67QPi0/URqu0Cp4J1I/AAAAAAAAAbs/0lG6m94Z6vM/s1024/Little%252520Bit%252520of%252520Paradise.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-TzF_LwrCnRM/URqu0RddPOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/gaj2dLiuX0s/s1024/Lone%252520Pine%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-4HdpJ4_DXU4/URqu046dJ9I/AAAAAAAAAbs/eBOodtk2_uk/s1024/Lonely%252520Rock.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-erbF--z-W4s/URqu1ajSLkI/AAAAAAAAAbs/xjDCDO1INzM/s1024/Longue%252520Vue.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0CXJRdJaqvc/URqu1opNZNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/PFB2oPUU7Lk/s1024/Look%252520Me%252520in%252520the%252520Eye.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-D_5lNxnDN6g/URqu2Tk7HVI/AAAAAAAAAbs/p0ddca9W__Y/s1024/Lost%252520in%252520a%252520Field.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-flsqwMrIk2Q/URqu24PcmjI/AAAAAAAAAbs/5ocIH85XofM/s1024/Marshall%252520Beach%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Y4lgryEVTmU/URqu28kG3gI/AAAAAAAAAbs/OjXpekqtbJ4/s1024/Mono%252520Lake%252520Blue.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-AaHAJPmcGYA/URqu3PIldHI/AAAAAAAAAbs/lcTqk1SIcRs/s1024/Monument%252520Valley%252520Overlook.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vKxfdQ83dQA/URqu31Yq_BI/AAAAAAAAAbs/OUoGk_2AyfM/s1024/Moving%252520Rock.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-CG62QiPpWXg/URqu4ia4vRI/AAAAAAAAAbs/0YOdqLAlcAc/s1024/Napali%252520Coast.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-wdGrP5PMmJQ/URqu5PZvn7I/AAAAAAAAAbs/m0abEcdPXe4/s1024/One%252520Wheel.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6WS5DoCGuOA/URqu5qx1UgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/giMw2ixPvrY/s1024/Open%252520Sky.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-u8EHKj8G8GQ/URqu55sM6yI/AAAAAAAAAbs/lIXX_GlTdmI/s1024/Orange%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-74Z5qj4bTDE/URqu6LSrJrI/AAAAAAAAAbs/XzmVkw90szQ/s1024/Orchid.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-lEQE4h6TePE/URqu6t_lSkI/AAAAAAAAAbs/zvGYKOea_qY/s1024/Over%252520there.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-cauH-53JH2M/URqu66v_USI/AAAAAAAAAbs/EucwwqclfKQ/s1024/Plumes.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-eDLT2jHDoy4/URqu7axzkAI/AAAAAAAAAbs/iVZE-xJ7lZs/s1024/Rainbokeh.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-j1NLqEFIyco/URqu8L1CGcI/AAAAAAAAAbs/aqZkgX66zlI/s1024/Rainbow.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-DRnqmK0t4VU/URqu8XYN9yI/AAAAAAAAAbs/LgvF_592WLU/s1024/Rice%252520Fields.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hwh1v3EOGcQ/URqu8qOaKwI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IljRJRnbJGw/s1024/Rockaway%252520Fire%252520Sky.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-wjV6FQk7tlk/URqu9jCQ8sI/AAAAAAAAAbs/RyYUpdo-c9o/s1024/Rockaway%252520Flow.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-6cAXNfo7D20/URqu-BdzgPI/AAAAAAAAAbs/OmsYllzJqwo/s1024/Rockaway%252520Sunset%252520Sky.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-sl8fpGPS-RE/URqu_BOkfgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/Dg2Fv-JxOeg/s1024/Russian%252520Ridge%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-gVtY36mMBIg/URqu_q91lkI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3CiFMBcy5MA/s1024/Rust%252520Knot.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-GHeImuHqJBE/URqu_FKfVLI/AAAAAAAAAbs/axuEJeqam7Q/s1024/Sailing%252520Stones.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hBbYZjTOwGc/URqu_ycpIrI/AAAAAAAAAbs/nAdJUXnGJYE/s1024/Seahorse.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Iwi6-i6IexY/URqvAYZHsVI/AAAAAAAAAbs/5ETWl4qXsFE/s1024/Shinjuku%252520Street.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-amhnySTM_MY/URqvAlb5KoI/AAAAAAAAAbs/pFCFgzlKsn0/s1024/Sierra%252520Heavens.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-dJgjepFrYSo/URqvBVJZrAI/AAAAAAAAAbs/v-F5QWpYO6s/s1024/Sierra%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Z4zGiC5nWdc/URqvBdEwivI/AAAAAAAAAbs/ZRZR1VJ84QA/s1024/Sin%252520Lights.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-_0cYiWW8ccY/URqvBz3iM4I/AAAAAAAAAbs/9N_Wq8MhLTY/s1024/Starry%252520Lake.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-A9LMoRyuQUA/URqvCYx_JoI/AAAAAAAAAbs/s7sde1Bz9cI/s1024/Starry%252520Night.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KtLJ3k858eY/URqvC_2h_bI/AAAAAAAAAbs/zzEBImwDA_g/s1024/Stream.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-dFB7Lad6RcA/URqvDUftwWI/AAAAAAAAAbs/BrhoUtXTN7o/s1024/Strip%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-at6apgFiN20/URqvDyffUZI/AAAAAAAAAbs/clABCx171bE/s1024/Sunset%252520Hills.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7-EHhtQthII/URqvEYTk4vI/AAAAAAAAAbs/QSJZoB3YjVg/s1024/Tenaya%252520Lake%2525202.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8MrjV_a-Pok/URqvFC5repI/AAAAAAAAAbs/9inKTg9fbCE/s1024/Tenaya%252520Lake.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-B1HW-z4zwao/URqvFWYRwUI/AAAAAAAAAbs/8Peli53Bs8I/s1024/The%252520Cave%252520BW.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PO4E-xZKAnQ/URqvGRqjYkI/AAAAAAAAAbs/42nyADFsXag/s1024/The%252520Fisherman.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-iLyZlzfdy7s/URqvG0YScdI/AAAAAAAAAbs/1J9eDKmkXtk/s1024/The%252520Night%252520is%252520Coming.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-G-k7YkkUco0/URqvHhah6fI/AAAAAAAAAbs/_taQQG7t0vo/s1024/The%252520Road.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-h-ALJt7kSus/URqvIThqYfI/AAAAAAAAAbs/ejiv35olWS8/s1024/Tokyo%252520Heights.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Hy9k-TbS7xg/URqvIjQMOxI/AAAAAAAAAbs/RSpmmOATSkg/s1024/Tokyo%252520Highway.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-83oOvMb4OZs/URqvJL0T7lI/AAAAAAAAAbs/c5TECZ6RONM/s1024/Tokyo%252520Smog.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-FB-jfgREEfI/URqvJI3EXAI/AAAAAAAAAbs/XfyweiRF4v8/s1024/Tufa%252520at%252520Night.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vngKD5Z1U8w/URqvJUCEgPI/AAAAAAAAAbs/ulxCMVcU6EU/s1024/Valley%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-DOz5I2E2oMQ/URqvKMND1kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/Iqf0IsInleo/s1024/Windmill%252520Sunrise.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-biyiyWcJ9MU/URqvKculiAI/AAAAAAAAAbs/jyPsCplJOpE/s1024/Windmill.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-PDT167_xRdA/URqvK36mLcI/AAAAAAAAAbs/oi2ik9QseMI/s1024/Windmills.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-kI_QdYx7VlU/URqvLXCB6gI/AAAAAAAAAbs/N31vlZ6u89o/s1024/Yet%252520Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-e9NHZ5k5MSs/URqvMIBZjtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/1fV810rDNfQ/s1024/Yosemite%252520Tree.jpg",};

}
```

Comment: You are looking for `thread.isAlive()`

Comment: Consider using [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s

Comment: Yes use `Callable` and `Future`

Comment: thread.isAlive() will work

Comment: Where to call thread.isAlive() @AmitDas

Comment: 1) Use Thread.join() in your main thread to wait in a blocking fashion for each Thread to complete OR
2) Check Thread.isAlive() in a polling fashion -- generally discouraged -- to wait until each Thread has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Thread.alive()` method.

Comment: Where to call Thread.alive() @Dark Knight & Most Important I have to nead Thread.isFinished() like function